# Independence of $S^* = \frac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{n}^{i=1}{(X_i - \mu)^2}$ and $\bar{X}$ where $X_i$ is i.i.d $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$? Not sample variance.

Tags: statistics, independence

Suppose we have $n$ samples $X_1, X_2, \cdots X_n$ from a normal distribution $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, and denoted their sample means $\bar{X} = \frac{1}{n} \sum\limits^{n}_{i=1}{X_i}$ and sample variance $S^2 = \frac{1}{n-1} \sum\limits^{n}_{i=1}{(X_i - \bar{X})^2}$, we know that $Y = \frac{\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}-\mu)}{S} \sim t(n-1)$, where $t(n-1)$ is a (studen)t-distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom.

Then if we denote $S^* = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n} \sum\limits^{n}_{i=1}{(X_i - \mu)^2}}$, would we have $Z = \frac{\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}-\mu)}{S^*} \sim t(n)$?

Someone has told me that the statement above is wrong, because $S^*$ is not independent with $\bar{X}$, then how to prove it?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. By $\sum^{i=1}_n$ do you mean $\sum_{i=1}^n$, or do you intend a factor of $-1$ as when integration limits are exchanged?

Comment: @J.G. sorry for the typo, I've fixed it. It's just normal sum notation. Can you explain to me why my notation have the connection to the integration, which is beyond my knowledge qwq.

Comment: @Henry sorry for missing the sqrt notation. I meant S* in the form of standard deviation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot be a Student law since it has bounded support. Without loss of generality assume $\mu=0$ and $ \sigma^2=1.$ Up to a constant $C_n$ depending on $n$ your random variable is $R_n=C_n\frac{X_1+\cdots+X_n}{\sqrt{X_1^2+\cdots+X_n^2}}$ and from Schwarz inequality applied to $a_i=X_i$ and $b_i=1$ we have $|R_n| \leq C_n\times \sqrt{n}.$

It is even interesting to compute the density of $$Q_n=\frac{(X_1+\cdots+X_n)^2}{X_1^2+\cdots+X_n^2}$$ as follows. If $X^T=(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ and if $J_n$ is the $(n,n)$ matrix whose all coefficients are $1,$ then for $0<r<n$ we have
$$\Pr(Q_n<r)=\Pr(X^T(J_n-rI_n)X<0).$$ Since the eigenvalues of $J_n-rI_n$ are $n-r$ and $-r$ with multiplicity $n-1$ we can claim that
$$X^T(J_n-rI_n)X\sim (n-r)Z_1^2-r(Z_2^2+\cdots+Z_n^2)$$ where $Z_1,\ldots,Z_n$ are independent $N(0,1).$ We get that
$$\Pr(Q_n<r)=\Pr(\frac{Z_1^2}{Z_2^2+\cdots+Z_n^2}<\frac{r}{n-r})=\frac{1}{B(1/2,(n-1)/2)}\int_0^{\frac{r}{n-r}}\frac{x^{-1/2}}{(1+x)^{n/2}}dx.$$ Taking derivative with respect to $r$ we obtain the density of $Q_n$ proportional to $r^{-1/2}(n-r)^{\frac{n-3}{2}}.$ In other terms $Q_n\sim nU$ where $U\sim \beta_{1/2,(n-1)/2}.$